# segmentation fault with strtok

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
        char path[] = "/fs/lost+found";
        char* temp;
        temp =  strtok(path,"lost+found");
        while(temp != NULL){
                printf("\n %s \n",temp);
                temp = strtok(path,"lost+found");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I wanted to extract the string lost+found. The above program goes into an infinite loop and prints the "/" that is before the delimiter "lost+found"

[root@rs]# ./a.out
Segmentation fault

Comment: I don't see a question, also, turn on compiler warnings, also, overwriting strings is undefined behavior.

Comment: Read the documentation for strtok.   After you pass the "path" the first time, you are supposed to pass NULL on subsequent calls to continue working on the same string.

Answer (score 3):

You committed two mistakes (as you can easily discover from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)).

1. `strtok()` takes as second argument a *delimiter*. In your case this delimiter is not `lost+found` but reasonably `/`.
2. inside the `while` block first parameter of the `strtok` function has to be `NULL` to make the function continue scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

Finally, you have to use `strcmp()` to discover if *processed token* is the string you're looking for.

So:

```
 ...
while (temp != NULL) {
    if (strcmp("lost+found", temp) == 0)
        printf ("%s\n", temp); // found

    temp = strtok (NULL, "/");
  }
 ... // not found
```

Answer (score 3):

from man 3 strtok:

> char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim); 
>   The strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens. On
>   the first  call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be
>   specified in str. In each subsequent call that should parse the same
>   string, str should be NULL.

Fix:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char path[] = "/fs/lost+found";
    char* temp;
    temp =  strtok(path,"/");
                     // ^^^  different delimiter
    do {
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        temp = strtok(NULL, "/");
                   // ^^^^ each subsequent call to strtok with NULL as 1st argument
    } while (temp != NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

It will print out the "fs" and "lost+found" tokens. You can add some checking whether temp has currently the value you're looking for and then you can store in other variable.

Answer (score 1):

**The delim argument specifies a set of characters that delimit the tokens in the parsed string.**

The 2nd argument that you have provided for strtok provides set of delimiters for tokenizing the given string, not for extracting a particular string

Use [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

```
temp = strstr(path,"lost+found");
```

This returns a pointer to the substring you are searching for

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a string literal, and `strtok()` will modify the string it's working on.